# Ricci tensor of the Grassmannian manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, curvature, grassmannian

I'm wondering if anyone could help me with calculating the Ricci tensor for the Grassmannian manifold. For Kähler manifolds we have:
\begin{equation}
    R_{\mu \bar{\nu}} = -\partial_{\bar{\nu}} \partial_{\mu} \log \det g_{\mu\bar{\nu}}
\end{equation}

For the Grassmannian, we are using the two-index notation
\begin{equation}
\Phi^{n\alpha} \quad,\qquad \text{where} \quad n=1\ldots N,\quad \alpha=1\ldots M
\end{equation}
And so, the Ricci tensor will have four indices, $R_{i\bar{j}\alpha\bar{\beta}}$.

The Kähler potential is given by:
\begin{equation}
    K = \operatorname{Tr} \ln (\delta^{n\bar{m}} + \Phi^{n\gamma}\overline{\Phi}^{\bar{\gamma} \bar{m}})
\end{equation}
Here we take the trace over the Latin indices, but we could also define $K = \operatorname{Tr} \ln (\delta^{\alpha\bar{\beta}} + \Phi^{n\alpha}\overline{\Phi}^{\bar{\beta}\bar{n}})$ and take the trace with respect to the Greek indices. The subscripts are reserved for lowering with the aid of the metric tensor. The latter is obtained as follows:
\begin{gather}
    G_{i\bar{j} \alpha \bar{\beta}}
    =
    \dfrac{\partial}{\partial \Phi^{i\alpha}}
    \dfrac{\partial}{\partial \overline{\Phi}^{\bar{\beta}\bar{j}}}
    K
    = \operatorname{Tr} \left\{
    \delta^{ni}\delta^{\alpha\bar{\beta}}(A^{-1})^{\bar{j} m}
     - \Phi^{n\beta}
    (A^{-1})^{\bar{j} i}
    \overline{\Phi}^{\bar{\alpha} \bar{l}}
    (A^{-1})^{\bar{l} m}
    \right\}
\end{gather}

How should I proceed from here? I guess, the answer should be
\begin{equation}
    R_{i\bar{j}\alpha\bar{\beta}} \propto (M+N)G_{i\bar{j}\alpha\bar{\beta}}
\end{equation}